# Change the Windows Automatic Updates Schedule on Server Core

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-update, windows-server-core

Server 2012 Core.

I can manually check for Windows Updates with sconfig option 6. I can set Windows Updates to automatic with sconfig option 5. Great.

[image]

What if I want to change that to 4 AM? What if I want to change it to only check once a week?

I sniffed around in `HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\` but didn't see anything that looked like it let me fine tune the schedule like I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming this isn't a domain machine you can configure through domain Group Policy, you should be able to connect a local Group Policy Editor mmc to the core machine from a full client and set the local policy that way (assuming 2012 still works as 2008 did):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/neilhut/archive/2007/11/06/managing-local-policy-on-a-windows-server-core-installation-set-to-workgroup-config.aspx

Comment: You could also install the minimal GUI on the machine, make the config changes, and then uninstall it, reverting it to Server Core. This only became possible with Server 2012.

Comment: Perfect. They are in a domain, but I didn't want to use domain GPOs because I didn't want to configure a separate GPO for each machine that I want to have different schedules. But they're lab machines so I don't mind automatic updates and reboots. Basically I just didn't want my domain controllers rebooting at the same time. I was able to remote manage the local policy from another machine with a GUI however, and I found the settings for configuring both day and hour.

Comment: Glad that did the trick. I agree that staggering reboots is a good idea. For this I've just turned off automatic restart by Windows Update and scripted a scheduled restart with appropriate delays between servers. Many ways to skin the cat.